# Method of deserializing an object which contains lists of other objects

Tags: c#, wpf, list, serialization, deserialization

I have an object GameOptions which holds a list of Tiles and a list of Options. A single GameOptions object is being put into a list, which I then serialize to give me a format which resembles this:

```
<GameOptions>
    <Tiles>
        <Tile1>
        </Tile1>
    </Tiles>
    <Options>
        <Option1>
        </Option1>
    <Options>
</GameOptions>
```

I am wondering how can I deseialize the saved file, back into a GameOptions object, which I can access the Tiles and Options values? Before, when I've needed to read an XML file I've just loaded the document, went through each node and copied the value, however I don't think this method would work again, because some nodes belong to the Tile class, whilst others belong to the Options class. Thank you in advance!

This is the code that I used to serialize in first place:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(gameSave.GetType());
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"savedmap.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, gameSave);
```

Comment: `I am wondering how can I deseialize the saved file` Use XmlSerializer. But better, before wondering, read some docs about xml.

Comment: Anything you serialize in a valid xml or json format can be trivially deserialized with the very same mechanism. What did you use to serialize this? And what did you try to deserialize it?

Comment: Just as with code, the schema should generally _not_ include `Tile1`, `Tile2`, ..`TileN` properties/keys. There is standard collection handling under both XML and JSON structures .. in any case, the only requirement is that the deserializer knows how to "undo" the serialization, which should be defined by a set of rules .. that you (or better, a standard serialization library) define.

Comment: Anyway, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

This might need a little tweaking, but here is a rough deserialization implementation:

```
    private GameOptions Deserialize()
    {

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameOptions));
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"savedmap.xml"))
        {
            return (GameOptions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```